# Ruby: A neat way to find the number of non nil records from a Hashie::Mash

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, salesforce, null

I'm using EJ Holme's rather excellent [restforce](https://github.com/ejholmes/restforce) gem to speak to my salesforce instance.

It's returning a hashie mash for a client record. I'd like to do a bit of built-in-method fu, but I'm getting stuck.

The hash returns around 550 array pairs of values. For instance `Restforce_hash.last` would return something like:

```
["field_title", "field_content">]
```

So far so great, I want to put a summary box at the top that displays a metric for how many fields are in use for the record.

If I call `Restforce_hash.length` I get the total number returned just fine.

However what I really want is the number of record pairs where the second item in the array (ie.. the "field_content" is *not* nil.

I was hoping there would be some great neat one-line ruby method for this like:

`Restforce_hash.not_nil.length`

But i'm not having just joy tracking something down... is there a way or do i have to iterate over the hash and count the number of != nil records?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
restforce_hash.count { |key, val| !val.nil? }
```

Comment: Brilliant thank you! 

I need to read up a bit on what you did there. What terms should I be looking for in the documentation? I see you've got the count built in method on the hash and an iterator in the pipes. What's the term for what the code in {} denote?

Comment: @Huw the code in the `{}` is called a block - http://rubylearning.com/satishtalim/ruby_blocks.html

Comment: Thanks that's a great start!

Answer (score 1):

```
Restforce_hash.select{|key,value| value.present? }
```

will return all the elements after excluding all the NIL + blank elements.
if

```
     Restforce_hash={:a=> "sss", :b=>"cvcxc",:c=>"",:f=>nil}
```

then

```
    Restforce_hash.select{|key,value| value.present? }
```

will return

```
{:a=>"sss", :b=>"cvcxc"}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know how many nil values there are in a hash, just use:

```
hash = {a:1, b:nil, c:2}
hash.values.count{ |v| !v } # => 1
```